Software to visually compare jpg/png with different compression levels
Looking for a program (windows) that will allow me to look at a jpg/png (or other image format) and change the compression level on an ad hoc basis and see what the quality of the resulting image is compared to the original.
I'm trying to avoid doing it manually (open the original file, save it with a particular level of compression, then open both files).

I found squoosh at https://squoosh.app/, which let's you use a slider to visually compare the results of using different compressions.
